# PWA: Why navigation to a URI only works when the the URI is registered in the manifest of the PWA

Tags: javascript, uwp, progressive-web-apps

I have created project "Progressive Web App" based on JavaScript with Visual Studio 2017. The created project contains a file `"package.appxmanifest"`. When the app is started it navigates to the URI, which is defined as StartPage in the manifest. This HTML-page contains a link, which should navigate to an other site.

```
window.location.href = 'other site'
```

This link works only when this URI is explicitly registered in the manifest as "Content-URI" (ApplicationContentUriRules).
Is it possible to allow all links without entry in Content-URIs?

Comment: Are you trying to mimic <a> behaviour? or What?

Comment: Can you post your web manifest?

Answer (score 1):

From MS Docs:

> Through ACURs, otherwise known as a URL allow list, you are able to give the URLs of your PWA direct access to Windows Runtime APIs. At the Windows OS level, the right policy bounds will be set to allow code hosted on your web server to directly call platform APIs. You define these bounds in the app package manifest file when you specify your PWA's URLs as ApplicationContentUriRules.
>
> Your rules should include your app’s start page and any other pages you want included as app pages. **If your user navigates to a URL that is not included in your rules, Windows will open the target URL in the Microsoft Edge browser rather than your standalone PWA window (WWAHost.exe process)**. You can also exclude specific URLs.

Maybe you can set a general allowance rule (not sure though if this is the right way to proceed):

```
<Application Id="App" StartPage="https://maApp.com/home">
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
    <uap:Rule Type="include" Match="https://*.*" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

In general with PWAs, you define a scope for your service worker in the web manifest. Then if the user clicks a link that navigates inside of this defined scope, the link will open within the PWA window.
If you want the link to be opened in a browser tab (hence outside of your PWA), you must add target="_blank" to the anchor tag.

If you want to read more about PWAs and web manifest I wrote an [article about it](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa).

**UPDATE**
With PWAs usually you want to navigate *only* within the scope of your app. If you need to redirect to an external resource/web site, the target page should be opened in an external browser page and not within the PWA scope. Therefore the current behaviour seems correct to me.

Comment: Definition in Manifest:

Comment: The wildcards changes nothing. When the link is clicked the Edge-Browser opens outside the app.

Answer (score 1):

UWP applications created with PWA, while relying on browsers, still feature the UWP sandbox application.

The link that appears in the `Content-URI` means that the link is trusted, and its sub-routes are accessible in the UWP window. But if you access an external link, the behavior will be directed to the browser, which will open the page by the browser.

You can use the wildcard "*" to match the links you need as much as possible, as described in the Content URI page, but that doesn't mean all links are allowed to be accessed in the UWP window.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use wildcards in the [Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-rule).

E.g.: `http://*.mydomain.com/pwa/*/content`

But as one [Dave puts it](https://deletethis.net/dave/2017-05/Application+Content+URI+Rules+wildcard+syntax):

> However the Store places restrictions on submitting apps that use the
>   http://* rule or rules with an asterisk in the second effective domain
>   name label. For example, http://*.com is also restricted for Store.

So, try to reduce the Rule-set the hostnames that are known in advance.